# insertAdjacentHTML is not working with documentfragment

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a parent and some elements inside, then i make a fragment and clone some nodes put them inside the fragment then try to insert the fragment inside the dom using insertAdjacentHTML code is like this

```
<div id="slide-container">
    <div class="page1">page0</div>
    <div class="page1">page1</div>
    <div class="page1">page2</div>
    <div class="page1">page3</div>
    <div class="page1">page4</div>
  </div>
<script>
var e = document.querySelector('#slide-container'), f = new DocumentFragment();
//add some elements to the fragment then try to insert them depending on some conditions
e.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',f)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document fragment is basically an abstract container for nodes. It's not HTML.

The `insertAdjacentElement` method doesn't work either. You can use `.insertBefore` instead.

```js
var e = document.querySelector('#slide-container'),
  f = new DocumentFragment();

f.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).textContent = "works!";

e.insertBefore(f, e.firstChild)
```

```html
<div id="slide-container">
  <div class="page1">page0</div>
  <div class="page1">page1</div>
  <div class="page1">page2</div>
  <div class="page1">page3</div>
  <div class="page1">page4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to convert the fragment inner to html or to string, i know it doesn't have innerHtml method but is there a way to do that ?!

Comment: I think you'd need to concatenate the `.outerHTML` of each of its child nodes. But if you want a string of HTML, why are you using a document fragment to begin with?

Comment: because i have to select some of these divs clone them, add them to document fragment and i have to reattach them to the dom again.

Comment: Instead of appending to a fragment, can you append to the `slide-container` directly? Unless you have an enormous number, I doubt there would be much difference in performance.

Comment: sometimes it is about 10 to 20 div's maybe more that's why i care about performance

Comment: So you need nodes to do cloning, and you want an HTML string... for what again? The HTML would need to be built, and then parsed, and then turned into DOM nodes. I can't imagine that would give you any performance benefit.

Comment: i've came to conclusion this is the only solution, insertbefore after cloning, or clearing the inner html of the container by `e.innerHTML=""` then appending the fragments from begining using appendchild.